# Need help editing a text file; removing all characters after a choosen character

Tags: python

I got the wonderful idea to try to use python to remove a certain section of the lyrics to a song. I want to remove everything before the column

example:

Lady: Oh how to make things fun… --- > Oh how to make things fun

Doll Girl: Oh how to make things fun? --- >Oh how to make things fun?

Doll Boy: Oh. How. To make things fun. --- > Oh. How. To make things fun.

and after a solid 20 minutes of thinking, this was my thought process before I realized I have no idea what I'm doing. since its just not working

```
import codecs


with codecs.open("potato.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as lyrics:
    readlines = lyrics.readlines()


separate = ':'
for lines in readlines:
    if separate in readlines:
        readlines = readlines.split(separate)[1]


with codecs.open("potato.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as lyrics:
    lyrics.writelines(readlines)
```

Comment: You are overwriting readlines in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Note the check to ensure that there is at least one separator in a line:

```
import codecs


def transform(filename, encoding='UTF-8'):
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding=encoding) as infile:
        allLines = infile.readlines()
    with codecs.open(filename, mode='w', encoding=encoding) as output:
        for line in allLines:
            parts = line.split(':')
            if len(parts) == 1:
                outline = parts[0]
            elif len(parts) == 2:
                outline = parts[1]
            else:
                outline = ':'.join(parts[1:])
            output.write(outline)


transform('potato.txt')
```

Comment: To avoid the last check, you could use `line.split(':', 1)` to get at most 2 parts

Answer (score -1):

```py
readlines = ['before column: a:b c d:']

separator = ':'
for line in readlines:
    new_line = line
    if ':' in line:
        new_line = separator.join([s for s in line.split(separator)[1:]]).strip()
    print(new_line)
```

output:

```
>>> readlines = ['before column: a:b c d:']
>>> separator = ':'
>>> for line in readlines:
...     new_line = line
...     if ':' in line:
...         new_line = separator.join([s for s in line.split(separator)[1:]]).strip()
...     print(new_line)
...
a:b c d:
```

Comment: how does this answer the question? Also you're missing indentation in the for loop

Comment: @EmiOB Indeed I was wrong. Thank you for your comment, I fixed the logic.

Comment: I don't think your for loop is doing anything now, you aren't using line in your code?

Comment: @EmiOB now it does :-) I added output, you can try it :-)

Comment: your output works, but I think thats because you've explicitly written a string into the for loop, I think this should be line instead?

Comment: @EmiOB Indeed :-) Thanks for highlighting that. I was doing it in hurry and forgot to clean up. Now everything should be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238979/discussion-between-mrvol-and-emi-ob).